# WIX Skip SetupType dialog

Tags: wix, skip

I though the below code should skip the SetupType dialog.

```
 <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
      Value="InstallDirDlg">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
      Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath"
      Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction"
      Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog"
      Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3">
        <![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND
WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]>
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
      Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4">
        WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR
        WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"
      </Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder"
      Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog"
      Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
      Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
      Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed</Publish>
```

However when I build it I still see the SetupType dialog which gives options to install Typical, Custom etc.....

I do not need this and just want to go to the option of going to the Install Directory page after the Licensce acceptance page.

How do I skip up the SetupType page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another dialog set, like WixUI_Advanced or WixUI_InstallDir, instead of WixUI_Mondo. See "Using Built-in WixUI Dialog Sets" in WiX.chm for details.